# Why this MarkerPatternSelector config in Slf4j+Log4j2 does not work?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j2

I am trying to limit exception stacktrace depth when logged from a specific place in code. Following http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Pattern_Selectors my configuration looks like this (key part):

```
<PatternLayout>
    <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}: %m%n">
        <PatternMatch key="ExceptionInterceptor"
                      pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}: %m%throwable{5}%n" />
    </MarkerPatternSelector>
</PatternLayout>
```

In the Java code:

```
@Slf4j
public final class ExceptionInterceptor {
   private static final Marker MARKER = MarkerFactory.getMarker("ExceptionInterceptor");

   public void intercept(Throwable t) {
      log.info(MARKER, "Got exception", t);
   }
```

And yet for some reason the marker does not seem to be matched, i.e. I am getting full stack logged. When I add `%throwable{5}` to the `defaultPattern` attribute, the stack is truncated as expected.

Here is the relevant DEBUG log during the startup (stripped timestamps & level). If I read it correctly, it seems to construct the matcher ok.

```
Building Plugin[name=PatternMatch, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternMatch]. Searching for builder factory method...
Found builder factory method [newBuilder]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternMatch$Builder org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternMatch.newBuilder().
Calling build() on class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternMatch$Builder for element PatternMatch with params(, key="ExceptionInterceptor", pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}: %m%throwable{5}%n")
Built Plugin[name=PatternMatch] OK from builder factory method.
Building Plugin[name=patternSelector, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.MarkerPatternSelector]. Searching for builder factory method...
No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.MarkerPatternSelector. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
Still building Plugin[name=patternSelector, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.MarkerPatternSelector]. Searching for factory method...
Found factory method [createSelector]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.MarkerPatternSelector org.apache.logging.
log4j.core.layout.MarkerPatternSelector.createSelector(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternMatch[],java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration).
```

What is wrong with this code above which results in marker not being matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your analysis and also can't find any issue with the configuration. (Thanks for showing the status log snippet.)

You may have found a bug. Please raise this on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker. Please mention the Log4j2 version you are using. (And if you haven't tried with the latest version, try that first. )

Comment: You were right. I was using Log4j 2.4, after upgrading to 2.6 the problem went away. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to upgrade to 2.8 since many, many bugs have been fixed since 2.6... :-)